# Why is Selenium Chrome driver not able to find elements below scroll bar?

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, selenium

I have been trying to write a clear dashboard step that would clear all objects we call widgets off of a dashboard page like this:

```
    public static void ClearDashboard(string widgetToKeep = null)
    {
        var widgets = Driver.FindElements(
            By.XPath(
                $"//div[@widget-name and descendant::span[@class='title' and text()[not(contains(., '{widgetToKeep ?? "dummyText"}'))]]]"
            ));

        if (widgets != null)
        {
            foreach (IWebElement widget in widgets)
            {
                var closeButton = widget.FindElement(By.XPath(".//span[@class='delete']"));
                closeButton.Click();
            }
    }
```

It totally works.
It gets all span elements back with a title and I can roll through those elements, get a span delete button for each one, and delete the widget with:

```
closeButton.Click()
```

Except for a widget object which is a bit off of the screen.
It can't seem to find the span button if the widget is a little off the screen.

> This is the exception:
>   InvalidOperation was unhandled by user code
>
> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (951, 760). Other element would receive the click: `<div class="scroll" ng-class="{'getting-data': gettingNewData}" scroll-pag="">...</div>`
>
> (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

You should use scrolling to reach every element before click using `IJavascriptExecutor` and wait until element to be clickable using `WebDriverWait` as below :-

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
foreach (IWebElement widget in widgets)
{
 var closeButton = widget.FindElement(By.XPath(".//span[@class='delete']"));

 //Now scroll to this element first 
 js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", closeButton);

 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(closeButton)).Click();
}
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't. The WebDriver is supposed to do this automatically by the spec: `they will implicitly scroll elements into view` © https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-interaction